# Per-repo github pages work, but main github pages don't

Tags: github, github-pages

I used github pages for a project and it worked fine:

[The gh-pages branch of a repo](https://github.com/jnvsor/apgtk/tree/gh-pages) lets me load [it's contents](http://jnvsor.github.io/apgtk/main.png) just fine

However, now I want to use the main per-person github pages it doesn't seem to want to work:

https://github.com/jnvsor/jnvsor.github.io should lead to http://jnvsor.github.io/ but while apgtk branch gh-pages works fine the `jnvsor.github.io` repository isn't working at all.

What's wrong?

Comment: If you click on Settings in the right column, what does it say in the "GitHub Pages" section?

Comment: Aha: `Your page is having problems building: Page build failed.` - didn't see that... Could it be the submodule? It's named the same as where a `gh-pages` repo would be put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

github.io crashes building a page if the submodule uses an ssh url. Apparently they don't support it. Changing my `.gitmodules` to use https fixed the problem